# Problem with PayPal using Braintree SDK when I try set up Payments in Euro. Can't debug problem

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk

1. I created PayPal Sandbox Business Account with EUR, USD and PLN enabled.
2. I created Sandbox REST API linked to account above.
3. I linked my Paypal Account in Braintree Sandbox ( https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/ ) in Account -> My User.
4. I typed in REST API keys in Settings -> Processing -> PayPal.
5. I made sure my default merechant is PLN currency.
6. I created backend methods for ClientToken and ProcessingNounce using Braintree .NET docs.
7. I prepared frontend using dropin from Braintree docs.

Code:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
                authorization: result.token,
                container: '#dropin-braintree-container',
                paypal: {
                    flow: 'checkout',
                    amount: '@Model.TransactionDetails.CalculatedTotalPrice',
                    currency: 'PLN'
                }, function (createErr, instance) { ... /* button listener and processing stuff here */ ... });
```

The code above works fine! I can finish transaction with Paypal client EUR account, Paypal client PLN, Braintree credit card etc.

Client told me that he don't want to recive payment in PLN currency, but in EUR, and there I am having a trouble.

I changed line:

```
currency: 'EUR'
```

And also I changed default merechant in Braintree to EUR (without changing merechant I was getting `"The currency of this PayPal transaction must match the currency of the merchant account (2091)"`)

Now when I try to pay with any PayPal account and any option within I am getting `"The customer's bank is unwilling to accept the transaction. For credit/debit card transactions, the customer will need to contact their bank for more details regarding this generic decline; if this is a PayPal transaction, the customer will need to contact PayPal. (Declined: 2046)"`. I can finish transaction only using braintree sample cards.

[image: Braintree transaction]

There is no way to debug this, API Calls in PayPal are telling me something is wrong, but I can't click and view details:

[image: PayPal debug]

When I switch back to PLN in frontend code and to default PLN merechant in Braintree, transaction works fine again.

I need help with that, it's not possible to debug it. Idk if I am missing some params specific for EUR currency or if its PayPal bug.

Thanks for help in advance!

**EDIT:** I have digged deeper, I checked POST request in Chrome dev tools on [Sandbox Api Calls page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/) to get details:

```
{
   "create_time":"30 Jan 2019 05:07:53",
   "correlation_id":"304384c194ece",
   "resource_id":"PAY-6JB373950C8856440LRI2DGI",
   "api_response":{
      "additional_properties":"xxxxxx",
      "body":{
         "debug_id":"304384c194ece",
         "details":"xxxxxx",
         "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
         "message":"The request was refused",
         "name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED"
      },
      "duration_time":"xxxxxx",
      "header":{
         "APPLICATION_ID":"xxxxxx",
         "CALLER_ACCT_NUM":"LG4QN5BPXPW7N",
         "Content-Language":"*",
         "Date":"Wed, 30 Jan 2019 13:07:57 GMT",
         "paypal-debug-id":"304384c194ece"
      },
      "status":400
   },
   "client_id":"ASKLWoEWn6q9ZNqkzpj7pulX4x0h9iD-Fy6_yzyfKaiNlHz7VMVwgPlk6Hpaq5-pG3_pcA84qIzOEx9q",
   "api_request":{
      "additional_properties":"xxxxxx",
      "body":{
         "payer_id":"CCD9AZVEJK8UN",
         "transactions":[
            {
               "amount":{
                  "currency":"EUR",
                  "total":"22.00"
               },
               "payment_options":{
                  "allowed_payment_method":"IMMEDIATE_PAY"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "header":{
         "accept":"application/json",
         "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
         "authorization":"xxxxxx",
         "client-auth":"No cert",
         "content-length":"152",
         "content-type":"application/json",
         "host":"api.sandbox.paypal.com",
         "paypal-client-metadata-id":"EC-6DS628633U9315453",
         "paypal-request-id":"1548853672_qc053cdc",
         "pp_remote_addr":"xxxxxx",
         "user-agent":"Braintree/1.0",
         "x-ads-si-context":"xxxxxx",
         "x-newrelic-id":"UAMPU1RWGwEJVlNaAQk=",
         "x-newrelic-transaction":"PxQFUVYHXAtTAlhWBwUCUAUHFB8EBw8RVU4aBAoOUgYBXAAFCARRVVMAA0NKQQ8FCFADA1UIFTs=",
         "x-pp-ads-performed":"xxxxxx",
         "x-pp-ads-request-id":"xxxxxx",
         "x-pp-ads-usecase-id":"xxxxxx",
         "x-pp-anomaly-detection-mechanism":"xxxxxx",
         "x-pp-corrid":"304384c194ece",
         "x-pp-idempotencyid":"304384c194ece_1548853673",
         "x-pp-silover":"xxxxxx",
         "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp":"apiplatformproxyserv",
         "x-request-id":"xxxxxx",
         "x-slr-orig-script_uri":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6JB373950C8856440LRI2DGI/execute"
      },
      "method":"POST"
   },
   "account_number":"2117554163912301260",
   "http_status":400,
   "url":"/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6JB373950C8856440LRI2DGI/execute"
}
```

According to [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#errors) this error can be basically anything.

**EDIT2:**

Sample request of successfull payment in PLN:

```
{  
         "create_time":"30 Jan 2019 06:58:59",
         "correlation_id":"7cabc2b46e5bb",
         "resource_id":"PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA",
         "api_response":{  
            "additional_properties":"xxxxxx",
            "body":{  
               "cart":"29R95576JY4406634",
               "create_time":"2019-01-30T14:59:03Z",
               "id":"PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA",
               "intent":"sale",
               "links":[  
                  {  
                     "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA",
                     "method":"GET",
                     "rel":"self"
                  }
               ],
               "payer":{  
                  "payer_info":{  
                     "country_code":"DE",
                     "email":"*****",
                     "first_name":"*****",
                     "last_name":"*****",
                     "payer_id":"CCD9AZVEJK8UN"
                  },
                  "payment_method":"paypal",
                  "status":"VERIFIED"
               },
               "state":"approved",
               "transactions":[  
                  {  
                     "amount":{  
                        "currency":"PLN",
                        "details":"xxxxxx",
                        "total":"22.00"
                     },
                     "payee":{  
                        "email":"*****",
                        "merchant_id":"LG4QN5BPXPW7N"
                     },
                     "payment_options":{  
                        "allowed_payment_method":"IMMEDIATE_PAY",
                        "recurring_flag":"xxxxxx",
                        "skip_fmf":"xxxxxx"
                     },
                     "related_resources":[  
                        {  
                           "sale":{  
                              "amount":{  
                                 "currency":"PLN",
                                 "details":{  
                                    "subtotal":"22.00"
                                 },
                                 "total":"22.00"
                              },
                              "create_time":"2019-01-30T14:59:02Z",
                              "id":"4AK709636U844620F",
                              "links":[  
                                 {  
                                    "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/4AK709636U844620F",
                                    "method":"GET",
                                    "rel":"self"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                    "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/4AK709636U844620F/refund",
                                    "method":"POST",
                                    "rel":"refund"
                                 },
                                 {  
                                    "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA",
                                    "method":"GET",
                                    "rel":"parent_payment"
                                 }
                              ],
                              "parent_payment":"PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA",
                              "payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER",
                              "protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE",
                              "protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
                              "state":"completed",
                              "transaction_fee":{  
                                 "currency":"PLN",
                                 "value":"2.21"
                              },
                              "update_time":"2019-01-30T14:59:02Z"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "duration_time":"xxxxxx",
            "header":{  
               "APPLICATION_ID":"xxxxxx",
               "CALLER_ACCT_NUM":"LG4QN5BPXPW7N",
               "Content-Language":"*",
               "Date":"Wed, 30 Jan 2019 14:59:03 GMT",
               "paypal-debug-id":"7cabc2b46e5bb"
            },
            "status":200
         },
         "client_id":"ASKLWoEWn6q9ZNqkzpj7pulX4x0h9iD-Fy6_yzyfKaiNlHz7VMVwgPlk6Hpaq5-pG3_pcA84qIzOEx9q",
         "api_request":{  
            "additional_properties":"xxxxxx",
            "body":{  
               "payer_id":"CCD9AZVEJK8UN",
               "transactions":[  
                  {  
                     "amount":{  
                        "currency":"PLN",
                        "total":"22.00"
                     },
                     "payment_options":{  
                        "allowed_payment_method":"IMMEDIATE_PAY"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            "header":{  
               "accept":"application/json",
               "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
               "authorization":"xxxxxx",
               "client-auth":"No cert",
               "content-length":"152",
               "content-type":"application/json",
               "host":"api.sandbox.paypal.com",
               "paypal-client-metadata-id":"EC-29R95576JY4406634",
               "paypal-request-id":"1548860338_ae402q2s",
               "pp_remote_addr":"xxxxxx",
               "user-agent":"Braintree/1.0",
               "x-ads-si-context":"xxxxxx",
               "x-newrelic-id":"UAMPU1RWGwEJVlNaAQk=",
               "x-newrelic-transaction":"PxRUBAIHCwsDXFJXVQdVB1YAFB8EBw8RVU4aVFxbUFQCVg9WCQdSA11UBUNKQQ8FCFADA1UIFTs=",
               "x-pp-ads-performed":"xxxxxx",
               "x-pp-ads-request-id":"xxxxxx",
               "x-pp-ads-usecase-id":"xxxxxx",
               "x-pp-anomaly-detection-mechanism":"xxxxxx",
               "x-pp-corrid":"7cabc2b46e5bb",
               "x-pp-idempotencyid":"7cabc2b46e5bb_1548860339",
               "x-pp-silover":"xxxxxx",
               "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp":"apiplatformproxyserv",
               "x-request-id":"xxxxxx",
               "x-slr-orig-script_uri":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA/execute"
            },
            "method":"POST"
         },
         "account_number":"2117554163912301260",
         "http_status":200,
         "url":"/v1/payments/payment/PAY-305699707J366792MLRI3XEA/execute"
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I repeated:

**1.** I created PayPal Sandbox Business Account with EUR, USD and PLN enabled.

**2.** I created Sandbox REST API linked to account above.

**4.** I typed in REST API keys in Settings -> Processing -> PayPal. (in Braintree sandbox)

And it works now. I double checked, setting are exactly the same as previous. I remeber in the **1** step I added EUR currency later, so it might be some kind of PayPal bug. Or maybe REST API App doesn't update currency settings from account.